# Remove button class on parent div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have several divs on a page with the same class that contain some buttons that are disabled by default. The goal is to highlight one of the divs on hover and to remove the 'disabled' class from the button.

I have been able to do it on ALL of the divs, but can't seem to get it working for only the element being hovered over. Tried $(this).find without luck.

```
     <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
$('.box').hover(
function() {
    $('.box .button').removeClass('disabled');
},
function() {
    $('.box .button').addClass('disabled');
}
);
```

Here I have it working on both elements but want to hover / remove disable class on individual box: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mgo6rpxs/2/)

Comment: Do you mean this? ~ https://jsfiddle.net/mgo6rpxs/3/

Comment: Oh I was so close! Thank you!

Comment: Your question says you tried `$(this).find`, why isn't it in the code you posted?

Comment: I should have included it in the code. I tried it incorrectly with .box .button instead of just .button because i'm already referring to the box element with (this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` to refer the hovered element and get element based on the context.

```
$('.box').hover(
  function() {
    $('.button', this).removeClass('disabled');
  },
  function() {
    $('.button', this).addClass('disabled');
  }
);
```

---

```js
$('.box').hover(
      function() {
        $('.button', this).removeClass('disabled');
      },
      function() {
        $('.button', this).addClass('disabled');
      }
    );
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #EFEFF4;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
}

.box:hover {
    border-color:#59c07b;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;

}
.disabled{background:white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
$('.box').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.button').removeClass('disabled')
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.button').addClass('disabled')
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you tried `$(this).find()`, but it should work for you. Here is a demo:

```js
$('button').text(function(){return this.className;}); //this line is for testing.

$('.box').hover(
function() {
    $(this).find('button').removeClass('disabled');
    $('button').text(function(){return this.className;}); //this line is for testing.
},
function() {
    $(this).find('button').addClass('disabled');
    $('button').text(function(){return this.className;}); //this line is for testing.
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="box">
            <button class="button disabled expanded">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```